# Remove several specific characters in a for loop for dataframe

Tags: r, string, gsub

I need to remove several specific characters in a column of dataframe, and I have tried code as this, but it does not remove any value, please help to check for the code.

```
for(i in Merged$root_name){
  i= gsub("[[:punct:]]$","",i)
  i= gsub(" ASA$","",i,ignore.case = T)
  i= gsub(" AS$","",i,ignore.case = T)
  i= gsub(" AB$","",i,ignore.case = T)
  i= gsub(" plc$","",i,ignore.case = T)
  i= gsub(" ltd$","", i,ignore.case = T)
  i= gsub(" corp$","",i,ignore.case = T)
  i= gsub(" limited$","",i,ignore.case = T)
}
```

Comment: Can we see a reproducible sample of your df `Merged`?

Comment: Do you mean `Merged$root_name <- gsub("(?:[[:space:]]*(?:\\b(?:A(?:SA?|B)|plc|ltd|corp|limited)\\b|[[:punct:]]))+$" , "", Merged$root_name, ignore.case = TRUE)`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B4rH1D/2).

Comment: Probably, the regex above is better used with `perl=TRUE` in `gsub`.

Comment: Sample for the root_name column as below:`Asia Offshore Drilling Limited|
Transeuro Energy Corp.|
Awilco LNG ASA|
London Mining Plc|
Nordic Financials|
Hofseth BioCare|
Petromena ASA|
Seajacks International Ltd|
North Energy|
IDEX ASA`

Comment: So, you just want `Merged$root_name <- gsub("(?:[[:space:]]+(?:A(?:SA?|B)|plc|ltd|corp|limited)|[[:punct:]]+)$", "", Merged$root_name, ignore.case = TRUE)`? Check [**this regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/B4rH1D/3)

Comment: Does `i` exist outside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all the patterns together

```
Merged$changed_root_name <- gsub("[[:punct:]]$|ASA$|AS$|AB$|plc$","",Merged$root_name, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

Comment: That is not the same what OP has, what if those values come in immediate succession at the end of the string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Do you mean string like `"ASASA"` would leave empty string as per OP's attempt and would leave `"AS"` in my code?

Comment: No, `ASASA` must be kept as is, I think.

Comment: I guess the pattern should be `"[[:punct:]]$|\\sASA$|\\sAS$|\\sAB$|\\splc$"`, i.e., including a space